# How does one get the type of a generic class with multiple type parameters? - C#

Tags: c#, generics

This compiles:

```
public class A<T> {
    public void test() {
        var a = typeof (A<>);
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
public class A<T,S> {
    public void test() {
        var a = typeof (A<>);
    }
}
```

I get the error: *Using the generic type 'A' requires 2 type arguments*

How do I get a reference to the type of this generic type with two arguments?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All you need is a comma:

```
var a = typeof (A<,>);
```

Note of course that this will return a `System.Type` that represents the *unbound* generic type `A`. Since the code is in a method that belongs to the type, you might just be looking for `typeof (A<T, S>)`, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

use A<,> not A<>

Answer (score 0):

Ani answer is corect, but i want to add solution for situation where you using generic class with more than two parameters:

```
public class A<T1, T2, T3>
{

}
```

You can get type by this:

```
typeof(A<,,>)
```

You need as many commas as generic parameters